# Eclipse Jboss Tools - Deploying parent child project

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, web-deployment, jboss-tools

I am new to jboss-tools. I am facing some configuration issues. I have configure jboss-tools and added wildfly 8.1  runtime.

I have one web application and many supporting java project. I have configured build path for the web application,added all the child projects in the build path.

Now I want to deploy them.

The problem is that child projects are deployed as "jar" files. They are deployed in web-inf/lib as jar file. I  am unable to debug them.

I want to delploy them as exploded archive in the web-inf/classes.

Using the "Deployment Assembly" when ever I add a project, it is added as for example "abc.jar"

Please help.

Thank you,
Rashid

Answer (score 0):

Deploying modules as exploded jars is a new feature in JBoss Tools 4.3.0.Final. From the [release notes](http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.3.0.Final.html#exploded-jars-in-web-inf-lib):

> In Wildfly 8.2, support was added for exploded jar deployment inside exploded wars. This has allowed our tooling to support this use case as well. This new functionality will be very useful when creating a modular web application, with different parts implemented in separate projects. Hot deployment of resources such as Facelets' XHTMLs is crucial for rapid development and testing

JBoss Tools 4.3.0.Final is available in the [Eclipse MarketPlace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jboss-tools)